# How to extract data to React state from CSV file using Papa Parse?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, csv, papaparse

I'm using [Papa Parse](http://papaparse.com/) to parse a CSV file for Graphs. I want to store the data in [React state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) after the file is parsed. Papa.Parse() doesn't return anything and results are provided asynchronously to a callback function. Also, setState() doesn't work inside a async callback. This question is similar to [Retrieving parsed data from CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266459/retrieve-parsed-data-from-csv-in-javascript-object-using-papa-parse).

I tried storing the data in state using below code, but as expected it didn't work.

```
componentWillMount() {

    function getData(result) {
      console.log(result); //displays whole data
      this.setState({data: result}); //but gets error here
    }

    function parseData(callBack) {
      var csvFilePath = require("./datasets/Data.csv");
      var Papa = require("papaparse/papaparse.min.js");
      Papa.parse(csvFilePath, {
        header: true,
        download: true,
        skipEmptyLines: true,
        complete: function(results) {
          callBack(results.data);
        }
      });
    }

    parseData(getData);
}
```

Here's the error I get when I set state inside getData().
[image]

The data is usable inside getData(), but I want to extract it.

How should I store the data in state or in some other variable so that I can use it for Graphs?

Comment: Can you rephrase your subject line into a question that is easy to read and understand? Your post doesn't contain a question until the last line, that is not ideal.

Comment: @Jacob please check the last line.

Comment: What exactly is the error message you get? (At this.setState({data: result});)

Comment: @Amanshu: I meant: the subject of your post needs to be a question. Stack Overflow is based around Questions and Answers. If your post is not titled with a question, how can there be an answer to go with it? (See the menu bar at the top: it says Questions first!)

Comment: @Larce question updated.

Comment: @Jacob is it better now?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem:

You try to call this.setState in the function getData. But this does not exist in the context of this function.

The solution:

I would try to not write function in functions, but write the functions in the class.

You class could look like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class DataParser extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    // Call super class
    super(props);

    // Bind this to function updateData (This eliminates the error)
    this.updateData = this.updateData.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {

    // Your parse code, but not seperated in a function
    var csvFilePath = require("./datasets/Data.csv");
    var Papa = require("papaparse/papaparse.min.js");
    Papa.parse(csvFilePath, {
      header: true,
      download: true,
      skipEmptyLines: true,
      // Here this is also available. So we can call our custom class method
      complete: this.updateData
    });
  }

  updateData(result) {
    const data = result.data;
    // Here this is available and we can call this.setState (since it's binded in the constructor)
    this.setState({data: data}); // or shorter ES syntax: this.setState({ data });
  }

  render() {
    // Your render function
    return <div>Data</div>
  }
}

export default DataParser;
```

Comment: @Larce hey guys, I'm trying to recreate something like this solution but require call doesn't work for me.. any ideas? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48800251/react-native-require-gotcha-works-for-local-image-file-but-not-csv-file-in-s/48803320#48803320

Comment: @Larce, why does the bare `this.updateData` work as the callback function for complete, but `this.updateData(result)` does not work? If I replace `this.updateData` with an anonymous function that takes result and console.log's it, it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the `getData()`:

```js
function getData(result) {
    console.log(result); // displays whole data
    this.setState({data: result}); // but gets error here
}.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [react-papaparse](https://react-papaparse.github.io) for an easy way. For more detail about react-papaparse please visit [react-papaparse](https://react-papaparse.github.io). Thanks!

Comment: Note that this was posted by the creator of react-papaparse.