# Papa parse assign variable on complete

Tags: reactjs, papaparse

I'm uploading a file using Papa Parse and having trouble assigning the `let data` variable within complete. The `data` variable returns undefined. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong here?

```
handleCSVInputChange(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let data;

  const file = event.target.files[0];

  Papa.parse(file, {
    header: true,
    complete: function(results, file) {
      if (results) {
        data = results.data;
      }
    }
  })

  if (data) {
    console.log('p', data);
  }
}
```

Comment: does the results.data, contain anything when you console.log

Comment: How is the code being used?

Comment: Yes. If I console.log results.data within the complete function it logs an array of data

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean `how is the code being used?`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266459/retrieve-parsed-data-from-csv-in-javascript-object-using-papa-parse Sounds similar to this question.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I have been looking for

Answer (score -1):

You have used `let` to declare `data`, `let` usually have block scope, try using `var`:

```
var data;
```

Instead of:

```
let data;
```

Comment: var doesn't work either