# papaparse results not saving to variable in Node.js/electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, papaparse

I'm trying to work with the output of a papaparse CSV read using the following:

```js
const file = fs.createReadStream('./data.csv');
let out;
Papa.parse(file, {
  header: true,
  dynamicTyping: true,
  complete: (results) => {
    console.log(results);
    out = results.data;
  },
});
```

The `console.log` correctly log the results, but `out` remains undefined... I feel like I'm doing it very similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49774653/12728698)... any help much appreciated

Note: although this seems very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26266459/12728698), I actually do need to persist the data into global state (not going to go into detail here)

Answer (score 0):

Whelp... [RTFM](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/blob/master/README.md#papa-parse-for-node).

> Papa Parse can also parse in a node streaming style which makes
> `.pipe` available.  Simply pipe the [Readable
> Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams) to
> the stream returned from `Papa.parse(Papa.NODE_STREAM_INPUT, options)`.  The `Papa.LocalChunkSize`, `Papa.RemoteChunkSize` ,
> `download`, `withCredentials`, `worker`, `step`, and **`complete`** config
> options are unavailable.

strange that the console log still runs...
Anyway workaround solution:

```js
const csvString = fs.readFileSync('./data.csv').toString();
let out;
Papa.parse(csvString, {
  header: true,
  dynamicTyping: true,
  complete: (results) => {
    console.log(results);
    out = results.data;
  },
});
```